# Dynamically send parameter in ajax-chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Jquery world.

I have these following codes:

```
$target.ajaxChosen({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<s:url action="getFilterValueJSON" namespace="/cMIS/timetable"></s:url>?filterKey='+keyword,
        dataType: 'json',
        jsonTermKey: 'filterWord'
    }, function (data) {
        var terms = [];
        mydata = data.valueMap;

        $.each(mydata, function (i, val) {
            terms.push({ value: i, text: val });
        });

        return terms;
    });
```

It seems the variable 'keyword' does not dynamically changed its value. The value for 'keyword' comes from an element with on change event. Would someone enlighten me about this on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, update your post with the change event code.

Answer (score 0):

its better you compose your url object just before call

```
function onclick(keyword)
{
   var url = '<s:url action="getFilterValueJSON" namespace="/cMIS/timetable"></s:url>?  
          filterKey='+keyword;
   ajaxCall(url);
}

function ajaxCall(url)
{
 $target.ajaxChosen({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        jsonTermKey: 'filterWord'
    }, function (data) {
        var terms = [];
        mydata = data.valueMap;

        $.each(mydata, function (i, val) {
            terms.push({ value: i, text: val });
        });

        return terms;
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am able to solve this.